# Не производится поиск файлов по всем дискам

Tags: c#

Имеется метод которые получает все диски

```
public static string GetAllDrives()
{
   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   try
   {
       DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
       foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
       {
          builder.AppendLine(d.Name);
       }
   }
   catch (Exception) { }
   return builder.ToString();
}
```

На выходе получаю:
`C:\ D:\ E:\` и.т.д диски

По ним я хочу пройтись и искать все файлы которые имеются там для этого я попробовал сделать такой метод поиска:

```
public static void SearchAllDisk()
{
   try
   {
     foreach (string list in Directory.EnumerateFiles(GetAllDrives(), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {
        Console.WriteLine(list);
     }
   }
   catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Но после запуска ничего не происходит, я пробовал добавить список в `List<string>`но и там тоже ничего не получилось, подскажите как через полученные диски пройтись по всем файлам в папках и подпапках?

Comment: Хотите сказать, что путь `C:\\\r\nD:\\\r\nE:\\\r\n` валиден?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция `GetAllDrives()` возвращает строку, в которой через `\r\n` перечислены все диски (что то типа `C:\\\r\nD:\\\r\nE:\\\r\n`). И вы эту строку передаете в `EnumerateFiles`.
Следовательно сначала вам нужно разделить эту строку на диски:

```
public static void SearchDirectory(string dir)
{
    try
    {
         foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(f));
         }
         foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(d));
             SearchDirectory(d);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}

public static void SearchAllDisk()
{
    try
    {
        string[] separators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] drives = GetAllDrives().Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string drive in drives)
        {
            SearchDirectory(drive);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Так же имейте в виду, что вы можете словить исключение при перечислении файлов одно диска (например, у вас недостаточно прав для просмтора этого файла) и тогда остальные диски не будут проверены. Поэтому лучше try-catch вынести внутри цикла.

Comment: Спасибо, я не заметил что он добавляет `\r\n` это помогло.

Comment: У меня такой поиск пропускает часть диска, почему так? ( добавил try catch {continue;} в цикле, и всё равно пропускает т.к не всё проходит.

Comment: Этот поиск отображает только файлы в кореновй директории диска

Comment: Какой тогда мне нужно использовать способ чтобы добраться до всех файлов по всем дискам?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду отображение всей файлов из всех директорий, то вам нужно рекурсивно заходить в каждую директорию и отображать файлы из неё

Comment: Я что-то не могу догнать, а этот пример можно как-то переделать чтобы он собирал все файлы?

Comment: Можно. Отредактировал ответ. Постарайтесь разобраться как это работает

Comment: Такой вопрос а `EnumerateFiles` вмести c `SearchOption.AllDirectories` должен же проходить по всем папкам ? или у него есть свои минусы?

Comment: Должен, но если случится исключение, то он не выведет ничего. Попробуйте, например, применить вашу функцию для диска, на котором у вас данные доступны из режима пользователя (а не администратора). В этом случае все должно сработать